# User restriction for Tfs work items

Tags: tfs

Is there any way to restrict one user from the team to get the alerts for the work items or any changes done in work item?
I was trying to add some new alerts under Team project alerts section in Project->Settings->Alerts->Team Alerts, but can not find any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup individual alerts to exclude one person.

You can also use a distribution list as the target that you can control independently.

Or you can create another "ghost" team that does not have that user and setup the alerts there.

Comment: Is there any way to create distribution list in tfs?

Comment: No a distribution list is created and maintained by your email server (exchange). You can then us the email in alerts...